# How to handle signing EXE file using SignTool returned error: 0x80096019?

Tags: return, certificate, signtool

I try to sign an EXE file using Sign Tool, once I did signing it's successful, but once I verify, it return this error. Anyone can help please.
Thank you, really appreciate the help.

```
Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: CARoot
    Issued by: CARoot
    Expires:   Sun Jan 01 07:59:59 2040
    SHA1 hash: 252B7A1148891AD28AD1D2A7CA4CDB7C841F5977

File is not timestamped.

SignTool Error: WinVerifyTrust returned error: 0x80096019
        A certificate's basic constraint extension has not been observed.

Number of files successfully Verified: 0
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use a CA certificate to sign. A CA certificate should issue a **Code Signing** certificate (EKU [`1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3`](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3) and [Basic Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pki/constraints-what-they-are-and-how-theyre-used) = LIMITED to 0 or false) that is then used to sign the executable.